# Why isn't my counter for counting elements which have the same level not counting completely or correctly?

Tags: c, counter

The counter does not increment correctly. How would I count elements which have the same level? It is not counting correctly right now, as it only counts once.

```
int countEls(ListNode *head, unsigned char level){    
    ListNode *p = NULL;
    struct personInfo *per;

    //allocate memory
    p = (ListNode *) malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    //update node
    p = head;

    //set the data of person
    *per=p->person;

    //initialize counter to 0
    int counter=0;

    //loop through list counting nodes with same priority
    while(p!=NULL){
        //p->person = *per;
        if(per->otherLevel=level){  
            counter++;
        
            //move to the next element
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: `if(per->otherLevel=level){ ` looks like you want `==`, and looks like you want to advance to the next element regardless of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator to compare in your if statement, `=` is assigning level to p->otherLevel instead of comparing it like `==`. You should also have check the next each time instead of only if the levels match. Your code is only running `p = p->next` if the levels are equal, which you don't want:

```
if(per->otherLevel == level){ //use double "=="  
    counter++;
    
    
    
}
//move to the next element
p = p->next;
```

Comment: I changed it and now it is not counting anything

Comment: you need to continue to the next element each time you iterate, not only when the if condition is true

Comment: get a segmentation fault(core dumped) error

Comment: Can you insert a print statement in your while loop to see if it the fault occurs immediately or somewhere during runtime?

Comment: it occurs after while loop